# Store attempted action when prompted for login and automatically complete upon redirect from auth

Tags: feature-request

When trying to upvote without being logged in, the login prompt pops up, go through login, redirected to the page was at before, and then have to do the same action attempted that prompted logging in (click upvote cause everyone is awesome).

This seems unnecessarily redundant.

Could we not cache the last attempted action that prompted the login and execute upon login so we do not have to be perform the same action twice?

Comment: Downvoter, should I rephrase or is this how a feature-request is given the nay (that's a bad idea!) on meta?

Comment: Second option Joshua, votes reflect agreement/disagreement with the request.

Comment: @Tensibai Ah, I see, thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh, and votes on meta doesn't affect reputation, negatively voted questions are absolutely OK as they show the community position toward a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting about reviews, flags, delete votes, edits, posts...
This seems like a massive amount of work for very little gain.

It'll be remarkably difficult to reliably catch all those actions, just so the user doesn't have to click twice if he hasn't logged in.

Comment: If this is true, and I don't think it is (that it's a massive amount of work), what is the value of lost actions because people don't follow through (ADD, balking from repetition) with what they were trying to do when prompted login? What is the value to stackoverflow that is lost? Even if only the upvoting and favoriting were covered suspicion is the gain would justify the time investment.

Comment: Keep in mind that this "system" would have to validate whether the actions are still valid when the user is logged in. Reviews could expire, posts can get deleted, new comments can be added in the meantime. Posts can be un-deleteable, closed, re-opened when you log in, etc. I only have to log in on SO twice per year, at most. This doesn't seem like that big of a problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus Scenarios you listed should already be accounted for, and I expect they are encountered regularly granted polling for updates and return to their computer after a break and try to do something.

Comment: @CodyGray changed the word to store, just for you Cody

Comment: @Cerbrus Also think that most power users (programmers?) do not sit on cookies for a 6 months at a time.. login twice per year, that's impressive.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: I use separate browsers for testing / browsing. I also don't wipe _all_ my cookies, when I just need to reset a single site. That's a beginner mistake ;-)

Comment: How could action needing reputation be available to anonymous (non-logged in) users ? (Getting to check how SO is anonymous, but I think only answer and votes buttons are shown)

Comment: @Cerbrus Spent enough time on start of day brain fart cache issues to setup defaulting to incognito.. hats off to you for you're scalpel like precision, I'd rather not think about it while I sip my coffee. :)

Comment: @Tensibai do you mean voting a question up?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Just checked, when logged off, accessible commands are vote up, vote down and comment, each prompting for logging in. So review, flags, delete, edits are not available and so should not be a problem...

Comment: *edits are not available* @Tensibai - You can edit without having an account. So it's not that editing is unavailable, it's just that it won't force you to log in first (though it will point out that you aren't logged in).

Comment: @BSMP Trying righ now from an incognito window, there's no edit link when you're not logged in, and trying to access the edit uri of a post says there's a pending edit...

Comment: @BSMP Rectification, there's an "improve this question/improve this answer" on older posts.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: That's why I use separate browsers. No worries about caching.